# Plot 0 values on a scatterplot with log

Tags: r, plot

I have two vectors:

```
x = c(0, 20, 10000, 50, 30000)
y = c(0, 3, 800, 1000, 7000)
```

I would like to do a scatterplot of my data in R. This is not complicated with the `plot` function. It would look best on a log scale, but values equal to 0 are not shown on the graph. I know `log(0)` is nonexistent. But I was hoping there was a way to show them on the scatterplot? (for example a point on the y-axis or the x-axis). Does anyone know how to do that?

Comment: Perhaps `plot(log(x + 1), log(y + 1))` and make sure the `+1` appears in the labels of the axis, and clarify it wherever necessary? If you force `log(0)` to appear on the axes as you suggest, how would you distinguish those values from `log(1)`?

Comment: I have occasionally plotted the zero points, separately, *on* the axis line as you suggest (you can use `par("usr")` to figure out where that is); I don't know if it's kosher but it seemed like a good idea at the time.  @Henrik: I would just make sure that the axis ranges include all the non-zero values, and make the convention clear in the figure caption.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to plot the data points, add a very small increment to all values:

```
plot(x + 0.1, y + 0.1, log = 'xy')
```

Now this hides which values are 0. This can be visualised well by using another symbol for null values:

```
plot(x + 0.1, y + 0.1, log = 'xy', pch = ifelse(x == 0 | y == 0, 17, 16))
```

Alternatively, you could also choose a different colour.

In order to plot the actual log values, don’s use the `log='xy'` argument but rather apply the log to the numbers directly:

```
plot(log(x + 0.1), log(y + 0.1), pch = ifelse(x == 0 | y == 0, 17, 16))
```

Comment: Thanks for this solution, I used it and it's perfect !

Comment: It works very well, do you know how to change the axis values​​, so that they take the x values and not log(x) values? Or something more intuitive than "log (x+ 0.1)"?

Comment: @user3383071 Check `?plot` for a documentation of the arguments that the function takes. The parameters you want are `xlab` and `ylab`.

Comment: No I do not speak the name of the axis, but its values. With your solution, I have following values : 1e-01 , 1e+01, 1e+03 .. but these are not the actual data. For example I want that the axis values ​​correspond to the real x and y values, and not log(x+0.1) and log(y+0.1). Do you think this is possible with the axis() function?

Comment: @user3383071 Ah, in that case plot the log values, rather than the actual values, in a log plot. See update.